# What is the opposite of Grammar Nazi?

Tags: discussion

Following on from the discussion about Grammar Nazis, is there an acceptable term for people who would consider themselves at the opposite end of the spectrum. It should be slightly pejorative but not give offence or lead to rows.

Comment: Do we really need more derogatory names for different grammar ideologies?

Comment: @ JSBangs: I agree : I don't think we should have any. But since the consensus of the 'Grammar Nazi' discussion was acceptability, maybe we should try to achieve balance. Personally I wouldn’t want to use any kind of labelling - let’s discuss each question on its merits.

Comment: I would quite happily call myself a grammar hippy. Simply because it sounds cool :-)

Comment: I'd probably call them Jejemon (though the term is probably not well known in other countries).

Answer (score 24):

How about grammar hippy?

Answer (score 10):

TV Tropes has an opposite of [Illiteracy communist](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/DarthWiki/IlliteracyCommunist).

Comment: I refuse to click that link.

Answer (score 3):

A loose grammon (rhymes with "loose cannon").

Answer (score 2):

Grammar Ally
...

Answer (score 2):

Post-grammarian

Grammar anarchist

Answer (score -3):

The Grammar Police